# NYC to Centralia

Tags: usa, new-york-city, pennsylvania

How can I get from New York City to Centralia, PA the easiest/quickest?

By car is estimated at around 2 hours 45 minutes, are there better methods available?

Comment: Are you sure you want to go to Centralia? The town is, like, [literally on fire](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/this-abandoned-pennsylvania-town-has-been-on-fire-for-53-years_us_55df6490e4b08dc09486d4a0).

Comment: @RobertColumbia I have a feeling that it's the reason why OP wants to go there

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  Private car is almost certain to be the fastest, so you must mean something else.

Comment: The nearest rail service appears to be Harrisburg, 60 miles away, which doesn't help much.

Comment: Susquehanna Trailways operates bus service from NYC to Ashland, PA, which is only 2.5 miles from Centralia (practically walking distance).  Only one bus per day, though, which makes the timing awkward, and overnight accommodations might be hard to come by in such a small town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What other method would it be? Bus? Train? Plane?

I think driving would be the best way to do it, and it looks to be a nice drive once you get out of the more dense NY/NJ areas.